# Как полностью удалить пакет из Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, visual-studio-code

Появилась проблема с visual studio code, через какое-то время работы с ней linux просто виснит, вот хочу полностью ее переустановить, но обычный `apt-get remove code` и `apt-get --purge remove code` не помогают, все что я делал с ней все остается. Открытые файлы, расширения, конфигурации. Так вот как удалить полностью пакет из linux (И поверьте VS CODE не единственный случай)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в этом виноват Visual Studio Code? Где остаются открытые файлы? Что значит «виснит»? Что показывает диспетчер задач, кто кого как нагружает? Что значит не единственный случай?

Comment: @andreymal 1) Когда просто используешь Linux все нормально. 2) При открытие vs code открываеются файлы которые ты ранее редактировал. 3)На что именно смотреть

Comment: @andreymal Я уже пытался его переустановить и удалил папку .vscode, а там были файлы task.json и launch.json. После переустановки я открыл конфигурации для Debug(То-есть launch.json) А при попытки открыть конфигурацию сборок ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите на свой линукс Synaptic командой `sudo apt install synaptic`, запустите из меню приложений или командой `sudo synaptic`, после запуска перейдите во вкладку **Установленные**, далее найдите пакет vs code и нажмите по нему ПКМ, в диаологом окне есть варианты: *Отметить для удаления* и *Отметить для полного удаления*. После клика отметить для полного удаления, всплывет окно где появятся пакеты которые удалятся вместо с vs code, нажмите **Применить** в всплывшем окне и **Применить** в главном окне

Comment: странно, я только что удалил свой так vs code, у меня исчезли открытые папки и файлы, сбросился конфиг

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt purge code
rm -r ~/.config/Code
```